# vertical line in tabular and size

Tags: tables, rules

In the code below, how do I add a vertical line to separate the second column from everything to the right of it? Also, the content of the table is too wide horizontally. I can see though that if columns 4 and up were aligned better, the content would perfectly fit the page. What would be the best way to do it? Thanks much in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[
    lmargin=1.0in,
    rmargin=1.0in,
    tmargin=2.0cm,
    bmargin=2.0cm
]{geometry}



\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.}
 %   \scalebox{0.95}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{}l@{\quad}lc*{11}{Y}@{}}
    \toprule
      & & &\multicolumn{11}{c}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\\[1mm]
      & & $a$ &$1\times10^2$ & $2\times10^2$ & $3\times10^2$ & $4\times10^2$ & $5\times10^2$ & $6\times10^2$ & $7\times10^2$ & $8\times10^2$ & $9\times10^2$
        & $1\times10^3$ & $1\times10^4$\\
    %\midrule
    \cmidrule[0.6pt]{4-14}
        \parbox[t]{3mm}{\multirow{22}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cmidrule{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$  & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  %  } % endof \scalebox
\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You can sort of get the vertical line by changing your `c*{11}` into a `c|c*{10}`.  But there is some residual vertical gap I don't understand.

Comment: Gaps in vertical line is caused by package booktabs. It is not designed for use of vertical lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without booktabs, replaced with `makecell`, that has commands for defining variable width horizontal rules. I also use the `cellspace` package, that defines minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and similarly a minimal spacing between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. The width of the table is OK if we use `footnotesize and reduce`tabcolsep` to 3pt.

I also loaded the `caption` package to have a correct vertical spacing between the caption and the top of the table (it swaps the values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip) and I simplified a little the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.0in, vmargin=2.0cm, showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{hhline, makecell}
\newcommand\thickhline{\Xhline{1.2pt}}
\newcommand\thickcline[1]{\Xcline{#1}{1.2pt}}
\newcommand\medhline{\Xhline{0.6pt}}
\newcommand\medcline[1]{\Xcline{#1}{0.6pt}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering\footnotesize\renewcommand\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \caption{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{}l@{\quad}lc!{\vrule width 1.2pt}*{9}{Y}Scc@{}}
\thickcline{2-14}
      & & &\multicolumn{11}{c}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\\[0.5ex]
      & & $a$ &$1\times10^2$ & $2\times10^2$ & $3\times10^2$ & $4\times10^2$ & $5\times10^2$ & $6\times10^2$ & $7\times10^2$ & $8\times10^2$ & $9\times10^2$
        & $1\times10^3$ & $1\times10^4$\\[0.5ex]
  \medcline{4-14}
        \multirow{25}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\enspace}}
 &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
 &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
  & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
  \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \cline{2-14}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.0}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{0.000000}
            & $00.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $000.00$ & $0,000.00$\\
            & &
            & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(000.000)$ & $(0,000.000)$ & $(00,000.000)$\\
    \thickcline{2-14}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]